# Evaluate $\int{\frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate: $$\int \frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x}  dx$$

I need a full answer and a detailed explanation as I don't know where to start.

Comment: Hint: Try writing both $sinx$ and $cosx$ in terms of $tan(\frac{x}{2})$ and then think about what substitution you could make after this.

Comment: Why are solutions using $u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ substitution getting downvoted without reason?

Comment: I think, because there is already another solution using the half angle tan substitution (though I'm not the downvoter). Unfortunately, they're downvoting the wrong one. (You posted first) :(

Comment: If you really needed it, you would have at least tried to find it.

Answer (score 6):

Making the substitution $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ is the preferred method for these types of problems, for sure, but not necessary for this particular problem.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\int\frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}dx&=&\int\frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}\cdot\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x-\sin x}dx\\
&=&\int\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}dx\\
&=&\int\frac{\cos x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}dx - \int\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}dx\\
&=&\int\frac{\cos x}{1-2\sin^2 x}dx - \int\frac{\sin x}{2\cos^2 x -1}dx\\
&=&\dots\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: How do I proceed?

Comment: In the first integral, make the substitution $u=\sin x$. In the second integral, substitute $v$ for $\cos x$. Then just work them out separately.

Answer (score 2):

**No need of  using $u=\tan(x/2)$**

**Easy method :**

Observe that  $\displaystyle\sqrt{2}\cos(45^0-x)=\sin x+\cos x$

So $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}dx=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\cos(45^0-x)}dx$

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \sec(45^0-x)dx=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\{\ln[\sec(45^0-x)+\tan(45^0-x)]\}+C$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sin x + \cos x}}dx$$
$$=\int{\frac{1}{\frac{2\tan \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}} + \frac{1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}}}dx$$
$$=\int{\frac{1+\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}{2\tan \frac{x}{2} + 1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}}dx$$
$$=\int{\frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{2 - 1 + 2\tan \frac{x}{2} -\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}}dx$$
$$=-\int{\frac{2d(1-\tan \frac{x}{2})}{(\sqrt{2})^2 - (1-\tan \frac{x}{2})^2}}$$

Now let $u=1-\tan \frac{x}{2}$ and use formulae to integrate.

Comment: Why an unexplained downvote??

Comment: @ SchrodingersCat: there is nothing wrong with your answer, just as there is nothing wrong with mine and I got two downvotes.  Downvoting without justification should be prohibited IMHO.

Comment: Not the one who downvoted, but it might have to do with the fact that you*re giving an almost complete answer without the OP at least trying to do some work himself/herself.

Comment: @Hirshy moorish first suggested this idea but OP showed no signs of having been benefitted. So I proceeded with the idea and came up with this. There's still the integration to be done and that makes my solution only 50% complete. The whole confusion starts with the OP not showing any effort and we then have to help almost guessing where the OP might be having problems. AND if my answer is "complete", then what is the answer above? INCOMPLETE? It got 6 upvotes. Take my point, complete/incomplete is not the case, it was a case of rogue downvoting or someone trying to win the Suffrage badge.

Comment: Not really a thing for the comments...still, I believe that if the OP shows no effort whatsoever, this answer might tell to much. I'm not judging the answer with 6 upvotes, but you asked for an explanation and I tried to come up with one. So either take it or leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=\tan \frac{x}{2}$.

Then, using the fact that

$\tag 1\cos ^2\frac{x}{2}-\sin ^{2}\frac{x}{2}=\cos x$ and  $\tag 22\cos \frac{x}{2}\sin \frac{x}{2}=\sin x$ write $\tag3 \sin x=\frac{2z}{1+z^{2}}\\ $ $\tag4 \cos x=\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^{2}}$ and $\tag5 dx=\frac{2dz}{1+z^{2}}$.

Now substitute,simplify and solve:

$\int\frac{1}{\sin x+\cos x}dx=\int \frac{2dz}{1+2z-z^2}=-\int \frac{2dz}{(z^2-2z-1)}=-\int \frac{2dz}{(z-1)^2-2} =\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{\left|z{-\sqrt{2}}{-1}\right|}{\left|z+\sqrt{2}{-1}\right|}\right)}{{2}^{\frac{3}{2}}}+C=\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{\left|\tan \frac{x}{2}{-\sqrt{2}}{-1}\right|}{\left|\tan \frac{x}{2}+\sqrt{2}{-1}\right|}\right)}{{2}^{\frac{3}{2}}}+C$.

Note we used partial fraction decomposition on the last integral.

Comment: I tell you solutions with $u=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ are getting targetted. I don't know why. Perhaps some rogue downvoter at work. Your answer is totally fine. +1 ... :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{\sec^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2}\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\int\frac{2}{-u^2+2u+1}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$2\int\frac{1}{-u^2+2u+1}\space\text{d}u=$$
$$2\int\frac{1}{2-(u-1)^2}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $s=u-1$ and $\text{d}s=\text{d}u$:

---

$$2\int\frac{1}{2-s^2}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$2\int\frac{1}{2\left(1-\frac{s^2}{2}\right)}\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{s^2}{2}}\space\text{d}s=$$

---

Substitute $p=\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\text{d}p=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\space\text{d}s$:

---

$$\sqrt{2}\int\frac{1}{1-p^2}\space\text{d}p=$$
$$\text{arctanh}\left(p\right)\sqrt{2}+\text{C}=$$
$$\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\sqrt{2}+\text{C}=$$
$$\text{arctanh}\left(\frac{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\sqrt{2}+\text{C}$$